# Set background color of TableRow

Tags: android, background-color, tablerow

I try to set the background color of a TableRow.
Currently I have this in my XML file:

```
android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
```

and i work great. But when it run

```
row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
```

the row disappears. Can someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to do:

```
Resources resource = context.getResources();
row.setBackgroundColor(resource.getColor(R.color.red)
```

Comment: getColor() deprecated

New;                row.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent))

Answer (score 3):

You can also try :

```
row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

This works for me in Android Studio 2.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

You must be missing the alpha value in your color definition. Verify it has 4 bytes, like `#FFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
row.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorAccent))
```

Answer (score -2):

Just write: `android:background="@android:color/buttonBackground"`