# Setting margin AND background color in a TableRow

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a strange issue when setting programmatically both margin **and** background color on a TableRow.
I already read **[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109747/setting-margin-of-a-tablerow-issue)** about margin, and **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077391/set-background-color-of-tablerow)** about background color, but apparently, I do things correctly. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

I create dynamically TableRows, which odds must be a specific color (to improve readability). I simply wrote this :

```
if(myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()){
do{
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tlp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(tlp);

    for(int j=0 ; j < TopTagsDetailsCursor.getColumnCount();j++){
        TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
        tv.setText(TopTagsDetailsCursor.getString(j));
        if (j>0) tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tableRow.addView(tv);                       
    }

    if ((i % 2) != 0){
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.table_row));
    }

    dataTable.addView(tableRow);
    i++;
});
}while(myCursor.moveToNext());
```

What I don't understand, is that on each odd row, with my custom background color, my custom margins (10 for top and bottom) aren't "applied" to the row, but they do are on even row.
Still stranger: if I remove the part of the code about custom background color, margins are OK everywhere !!

So, **why my custom margins aren't ok when I put custom background color ??**

*PS: I even tried to move some lines of code (especially the addView(tableRow) and those about the color), but no effect.*

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't explain why it didn't work before, but at least I finally found a "fix".
I remove these lines :

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
tlp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(tlp);
```

And I replaced :

```
tableRow.addView(tv);
```

by :

```
tableRow.addView(tv, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 80)); //or any other value
```

and it works fine finally... even if I don't understand why my first solution didn't work :) *(feel free to explain me why !)*